# what happens if default value is null and convert to string

Tags: c#

to be more specific, I have DateTime? BirthDate

my question is what will happen in this case:

```
lblBirthDate.Text = myObject.BirthDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString();
```

if BirthDate will be null. I have resharper installed, and it doesn't warn me that I could have a null problem there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `BirthDate` is `null`, you get the localized string representation of the default instance of `DateTime`. That is, you'll get the string representation of 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001.

You don't get a warning from ReSharper because you don't have a null problem there. It is not a runtime exception to call `Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault` on a null instance of a `Nullable<T>`. Instead, you get the default value if you have a null instance. That's exactly what `GetValueOrDefault` means: get `Value` if `HasValue` is `true`, otherwise get the default value for the underlying struct type.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: No, it wouldn't, because you're dealing with Nullable types. Nullable types get lifted for various operators by the compiler automagically (meaning the operators that are defined on the non-nullable type is now able to handle nullable-types). Try it with any nullable type and see what happens when you call ToString() on a Nullable<T> that has a null value. You'll see that it goes to the `default(T)` representation.

Comment: @SPFiredrake: No, that's not right. If you call `ToString` on a null instance of a `Nullable<T>`, you get `String.Empty`. If you call `GetValueOrDefault` on a `Nullable<T>`, you get `default(T)`. Then, if you call `ToString` on that, then you get a string representation of the `default(T)`. Thus, `Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault().ToString() != Nullable<T>.ToString()` if the instance is `null` unless the string representation of `default(T)` happens to be `String.Empty` (it's not for `DateTime`, for example).

Comment: @gdoron: Note that `Nullable<T>` is a value type, not a reference type. In fact it is a struct.

Comment: @Jason: You are correct, I was thinking of GetValueOrDefault (which is what I usually use).

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure `GetValueOrDefault` returns `DateTime.MinValue` in the case of null.

Here's a few ways you can handle null values:

```
DateTime? myNullDate = null;

DateTime myDate;
myDate = myNullDate ?? DateTime.Now; // myDate => DateTime.Now
myDate = myNullDate ?? default(DateTime); // myDate => DateTime.MinValue
myDate = myNullDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now); // myDate => DateTime.Now
myDate = myNullDate.GetValueOrDefault(); // myDate => DateTime.MinValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Resharper won't show you any error because the default value for DateTime is 1/1/1 00:00:00. You can get the default value for any type using the default operator:

```
DateTime defaultDateTime = default(DateTime);
```

This value is exactly the same as `DateTime.MinValue`

If you need to use nulls, you must declare your property as nullable:

```
DateTime? BirthDay { get; set; };
```

The nullable DateTime `DateTime?` supports calling `ToString()` without error even if the value is null, giving an empty string if so. Then you don't have to worry about nulls.

Is much more consistent using a nullable DateTime than having a special value to represent missing values, like `default(DateTime)`, i.e. `DateTime.MinValue;`